# How to handle day light saving in oozie coordinator?

Tags: hive, bigdata, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

Due to day light saving all my scheduled jobs(using oozie) are running later one hour.

**Before DST** : My jobs runs every day at 8:00 pm
**after DST**: Now job is running at 9:00 pm

could any tell is there way to handle day light saving in oozie cooridnator ?

Comment: No. Oozie works in UTC, because other time zones are too dangerous -- with time gaps & time overlaps. Google for "fallacies developers believe about time"...

Comment: But you can push the "nominal exec time" from Coordinator to Workflow, and start with a shell action that converts the UTC time to local time & checks whether summer/winter period & sleep 1 hr if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a tip?

I have scheduled coordinators who have to run every day at a fixed time, regardless of summer or winter time, with a `cron` expression.

```
< coordinator-app xmlns = "uri:oozie:coordinator:0.5" end="2024-12-04T23:59Z" frequency="6 10 * * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN" name="COORD_SAMPLE"start="2019-12-04T00:01Z" timezone="Europe / Paris ">
```

But in the transition to summer time, there will be a shift of 1 hour as I had the transition from summer to winter time.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the answer is to use `${coord:days(1)}` for the `frequency`. This EL function can calculate how many minutes is there in a "day" so that the job will be triggered at a constant local hour. local is determined by your timezone value.